# serializing array using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a 2 classes as follows

```
class Rules{

 @JsonProperty("rules")
 Rule [] rules
}

class Rule{
 @JsonProperty("a1")
String attrubite1;
}
```

I have serialized this using json and it produces
something like

```
{
    "rules": [{
       "a1": "somedataForRule1"
    }, {
        "a1": "somedataforTule1"
    }]
}
```

I want the json to be like

```
{
    "rules": ["rule":{
       "a1": "somedataForRule1"
    }, 
    "rule":{
        "a1": "somedataforTule1"
    }]
}
```

How do i do it?

MY code :

```
Rules rules = new Rules();
 rules.setRules(new Rule[]{r1,r2});
 Strings = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rules);
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Hiranya added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In arrays we cannot have keys. Arrays only have indexes as keys.
So the following is invalid json

```
[
    "a": {...}
]
```

To have keys we will need a map. So the following is valid.

```
{
    "a": {...}
}
```

So what you want is not possible, because you are asking jackson to create invalid json. Only way to hack this is to create your own utility.

**Edit**

> Are u sure its invalid json?

[www.json.org](http://www.json.org/)
[image]

Comment: Are u sure its invalid json?